# MongoDB, return recent document for each user_id in collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Looking for similar functionality to Postgres' Distinct On.

Have a collection of documents {user_id, current_status, date}, where status is just text and date is a Date.  Still in the early stages of wrapping my head around mongo and getting a feel for best way to do things.

Would mapreduce be the best solution here, map emits all, and reduce keeps a record of the latest one, or is there a built in solution without pulling out mr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`distinct` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct), however I'm not sure that's what you need. Distinct is kind of a "query" command and with lots of users, you're probably going to want to roll up data not in real-time.

Map-Reduce is probably one way to go here.

**Map Phase:** Your `key` would simply be an ID. Your `value` would be something like the following `{current_status:'blah',date:1234}`.

**Reduce Phase:** Given an array of values, you would grab the most recent and return only it.

To make this work optimally you'll probably want to look at a new feature from 1.8.0. The ["re-reduce" feature](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/1.8+Release+Notes). Will allow you to process only new data instead of re-processing the whole status collection.

***The other way*** to do this is to build a "most-recent" collection and tie the status insert to that collection. So when you insert a new status for the user, you update their "most-recent".

Depending on the importance of this feature, you could possibly do both things.

Comment: Thanks I think both of those approaches might be worth looking into, especially the re-reduce.

Comment: Thinking about the most recent collection approach, it seems like that would add a lot of overhead to the insert process, something I'd like to avoid since it was part of my reason going with mongo anyways.

I'd need to search/remove status with the id I'm inserting for each id.  While this shoudln't be fast since its indexed and a smaller collection, mongo does have the "problem" of locking the whole collection for deletes, so it "seems" like that'd be a big tradeoff to make.

Comment: You can do an `upsert` that will be very quick. The `upsert` is *"if exists update else create"*. So there's no deletion or no additional query. In JS this looks like the following `db.most_recent.update({_id:user_id},{status:"blah"},false,true)`, check your language driver for "upsert".

Comment: Yep, I remembered upsert not too long after my last comment.  Since I have a usergroup thats growing rather quickly I think the recent collection is the best way to do this so I'm moving that direction.
Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Current solution that seems to be working well.

```
map = function () {emit(this.user.id, this.created_at);}

//We call new date just in case somethings not being stored as a date and instead just a string, cause my date gathering/inserting function is kind of stupid atm

reduce = function(key, values) { return new Date(Math.max.apply(Math, values.map(function(x){return new Date(x)})))}


res = db.statuses.mapReduce(map,reduce);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same result would be to use the `group` command, which is a kind of a mr-shortcut that lets you aggregate on a specific key or set of keys. 
In your case it would read like this:

```
db.coll.group({ key : { user_id: true },
                reduce : function(obj, prev) { 
                           if (new Date(obj.date) < prev.date) { 
                             prev.status = obj.status; 
                             prev.date = obj.date; 
                           }
                         },
              initial : { status : "" }
})
```

However, unless you have a rather small fixed amount of users I strongly believe that a better solution would be, as previously suggested, to keep a separate collection containing only the latest status-message for each user.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting group, however with group not being able to be used with sharding, thats a solution I'm going to avoid.